# Implementing Single Sign on using ADFS

Tags: single-sign-on, kerberos, saml-2.0, adfs2.0, spring-security-kerberos

I am new to ADFS/SSO world and currently working on feature to implement Single Sign On (SSO) using AD FS for our Java based web application and Windows native agent.

Below are our requirement :

1. Users should be logged in automatically(Without asking for username/password) to our windows agent if they have logged into their system using their domain credentials.
2. The solution should work even if they are outside the corporate network

I have been reading on Internet but things are still confusing. I have following questions :

1. Will kerberos based authentication suits my requirement?
2. Can It be integrated with AD FS? So that the solution will work even if the user is not in corporate network?
3. Or are there any other solutions? Our Product is Java based and uses Spring framework.

Thanks in Advance,
Praveen

Answer (score 3):

*Users should be logged in automatically*

This will work if the browser is correctly configured for IWA

*The solution should work even if they are outside the corporate network*

No - Kerberos won't work so you have to use FBA

*Can It be integrated with AD FS? So that the solution will work even if the user is not in corporate network?*

Yes - you need to install ADFS WAP as well. Use split DNS. Internal users direct to ADFS == IWA. External users direct to WAP = FBA.

*Our Product is Java based and uses Spring framework*

Use Spring SAML

For desktop, you have a problem. SAML relies on browser redirects so you need an embedded browser or something. You could use OpenID Connect / OAuth (REST API) but you have tagged the question with ADFS 2.0 which has no such support.

In the Windows world (WPF, console via C# etc.), desktop connects to ADFS via WCF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But can I use it for windows desktop application as well?

Comment: Okay. Can I use ADFS 3 + OAuth and achieve both web and client SSO?are there any popular java/spring plug-in for the same?

Comment: No - ADFS 3.0 only supports OAuth for webapi and has no OpenID Connect support, You need ADFS 4.0 (Server 2016) - out in September.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in ADFS 2016, with Windows 10 domain joined devices, they can also be Azure AD registered. With device write back of this, there is a SSO artifact from ADFS that is integrated into Windows 10 desktop login. In this world, you will also get desktop SSO from the extranet.

Comment: can the sso happen without AAD, I have a similar situation the client is a .net application (runs on win7/8/10 domain joined machine on intranet) and server is java (tomcat) extranet. Can I use WIF on client and Spring saml to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

For your Java app, you should use [spring-webmvc-pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/spring-webmvc-pac4j) for Spring MVC or [j2e-pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/j2e-pac4j) with only J2E filters (or at worst: [spring-security-pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/spring-security-pac4j) with Spring Security) + [pac4j-saml](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/wiki/Clients#saml-support-pac4j-saml-module) for ADFS + [pac4j-oauth](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/wiki/Clients#oauth-support-pac4j-oauth-module) if want to use the OAuth protocol + [pac4j-oidc](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/wiki/Clients#openid-support-pac4j-openid-module) if you want to use the OpenID Connect protocol.

Using [pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j) will be much easier and consistent to support multiple protocols.